# Magento theme problem

Tags: templates, magento, themes, directory, config

I tried creating a new theme in Magento by creating the following folders:

**/app/design/frontend/interface/default**

**/skin/frontend/interface/default**

I copied into these folders the entire content of the base/default folders (in both skin and design).

I enabled the theme bu putting "interface" in "current package name" for a website and expected it to look like the theme I had copied, but for some reason, nothing in the head is loaded. No css, js, ...

I checked and all my xml/css/js files are all there though ... What might the problem be?

The .phtml files are all being loaded.

**EDIT:**

I also noticed that selecting "base" as default package does not work either, but if you select "default", then it does load the base theme phtml files with some base and soem default css ...

**EDIT2**

Fixed, not sure where the error was ...

Answer (score 1):

Did you refresh the caches?

On development stations its good practice to disable all Magento caches, until everything works, because sometimes it's really easy to forget to refresh them.

Comment: Yes, caching is off and cleared them by hand. This theme is being loaded for a website, just not just another store, but the default theme always worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Magento have a structure, its better to put your [custom magento theme design](http://www.magentoconnect.us/magento-theme-development-design.php/) folder into app/design/frontend/default/themename this is PHTML path and for CSS and JS you can put the folder in skin/frontend/default/themename

After that just delete the cache and enable the theme from either admin > system > configuration > design or from admin > system > design and select you [custom magento theme](http://www.magentoconnect.us/magento-theme-template-customization.php/)